# Compiling against a different version of libc?

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, makefile

You can run a command such as `CC=gcc4.5 make` to use gcc4.5 as your compiler.

Is there such a command for changing where you are getting libc stuff from? Such as `LIBC=${HOME}/glibc-2.16` or something?

The version I have installed in /usr/ is 2.13, but I need to use 2.14 to compile something, so I've got glibc-2.14 all compiled and ready to go, but I'm not sure how to use it instead of the default one.

Comment: Are you talking about `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host

Comment: Evidently yes, that fixed it! Thank you @BMW!

Comment: oh, I should answer it.

Comment: @BMW Yes you should, what are you waiting for ?